# Get ViewModel for products and categories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am developing an ecommerce website and I use three tables for the management of products and categories.

I would need one or more linq queries with entity framework to get the list of mother categories, daughters and the list of related products.

There is a Category table, like:

Id
NameCat
ParentId

There is a products table, like:

Id
Name
Live
Info, etc.

There is a product-category table, like:

Id
categoryId
productId
sortOrder

This is my viewmodel

```
public class CatViewModel
    {
        public int IdCat { get; set; }
        public string NameCat { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public List<CatViewModel> Children { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }
```

Clearly each parent category must have the complete list of products of all its child categories

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. In the method that is supposed to return view with this CatViewModel you can do this:

```
var mainObject = Context.Category.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdCat == "YOUR PARAMETER OF ID HERE");
var viewModel = new CatViewModel
{
   IdCat = mainObject.IdCat,
   NameCat = mainObject.NameCat,
   ParentId = mainObject.ParentId,
   Children = Context.Children(query here).ToList(),
   Products = Context.Products(query here).ToList()
};
```

Solution 2:

You can first create:

```
var listChildern = Context.Children(query here).ToList();
var listProducts = Context.Products(query here).ToList();
```

Then return your viewModel which you fill just like this:

```
var mainObject = Context.Category.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdCat == "YOUR PARAMETER OF ID HERE");
var viewModel = new CatViewModel
{
   IdCat = mainObject.IdCat,
   NameCat = mainObject.NameCat,
   ParentId = mainObject.ParentId,
   Children = listChildern ,
   Products = listProducts 
};
```

Comment: I have three tables.
I need a CatViewModel list type model, I tried this:
var cats = db.Cats.AsEnumerable() // <-- Force full execution (loading) of the above
                                .Where(e => e.ParentId == null) // <-- then apply the root filter
                                .ToList();
                var myList = cats.Select(c => new CatViewModel
                {
                    IdCat = c.IdCat,
                    NameCat = c.Nomecat_it,
                    Children = c.Children,
                    Products = ???
                }).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I have three tables.
I need a CatViewModel list type model, I tried this:

```
var cats = db.Cats.AsEnumerable() // <-- Force full execution (loading) of the above 
.Where(e => e.ParentId == null) // <-- then apply the root filter 
.ToList(); 

var myList = cats.Select(c => new CatViewModel {
 IdCat = c.IdCat, 
NameCat = c.Nomecat, 
Children = c.Children, 
Products = ??? 
}).ToList();
```